# INJECT_EVENTS on unrooted phone

Tags: java, android

I have tried to use an INJECT_EVENTS permission on an unrooted phone (Android 6 or below).
I would like to know which android version I need to have to use an INJECT_EVENTS permission without crashing my app.Does it work in Android 4? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INJECT_EVENTS` is a `signature`-level permission. It has been that way at least through Android 4.0, and perhaps earlier. You cannot hold this permission unless your app is signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I used Android 3, would the app be crashing?

Comment: @ilan: There are no current Android devices running Android 3.x.

Comment: I need to do some Automation at my work, and my company must have old Android devices somewhere. I just need one mobile.

Comment: @ilan: You are welcome to go through the Android source code history to find what the `protectionLevel` was for `INJECT_EVENTS` for various Android versions. [Here is the `master` branch edition of the relevant file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml).